# "The action 'execute' could not be found for GraphqlController" when using GraphQL on an API only Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, rails-api

I've posted a bug for this on `rmosolgo/graphql-ruby` but just in case I may be doing something wrong, I'm hoping to see if anyone else has a solution to my problem.

When creating an API only rails application it seems that Rails believes the `execute` method in my `GraphqlController` is missing.

Here is my graphql_controller.rb file:

```
class GraphqlController < ApplicationController
  # If accessing from outside this domain, nullify the session
  # This allows for outside API access while preventing CSRF attacks,
  # but you'll have to authenticate your user separately
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def execute
    variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
    query = params[:query]
    operation_name = params[:operationName]
    context = {
      # Query context goes here, for example:
      # current_user: current_user,
    }
    result = RailsApiGraphqlExecuteTestSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, operation_name: operation_name)
    render json: result
  rescue => e
    raise e unless Rails.env.development?
    handle_error_in_development e
  end
# ... continues on
end
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

when I run `rake routes` this is what I get:

```
prompt> rake routes                                   
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern          Controller#Action
                              graphql POST   /graphql(.:format)   graphql#execute
... continues on
```

You should be able to reproduce this with the following command line steps:

```
rails new execute-test --api
cd execute-test
vim Gemfile # or open an editor and add "gem 'graphql'"
bundle
rake db:create
rails g graphql:install
rake routes # to test that the route exists
rails s
```

When you use an app like GraphiQL and go to http://localhost:3000/graphql you'll get the following error:

```
Started POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-10-15 16:23:29 -0700
   (0.3ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'execute' could not be found for GraphqlController):
... strack trace continues ...
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: @Hugo look at my answer. If you comment out that line from your Graphql controller, this will work. The issue is that API only rails server doesn't use cookies so it doesn't make sense to have this line there anyway. I posted this as an issue to GraphQL's repo and they will comment this line out and allow users to opt in, instead of try to figure out why its doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this line in the `execute` method:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

is what caused the problem. I'll have to look into this some more. +1 and I'll even mark the answer correct if someone can figure out why this is happening.

**Edit:** The reason this is happening is because this method assumes you're inheriting from `ActionController::Base` and not `ActionController::API` (which doesn't have this method). the API class is supposed to be lighter and therefore doesn't support cookies/sessions out of the box.